# Regular expression matched first 3 character of string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a pattern regular expression that is matching of first 3 character of string.
For example , I have two number like this:
`011569875` and `041568956`

If I found first 3 character `011` ,then I will print `011569875`

Comment: You don't need a regular expression to test that, why not simply use `substr()`?

Comment: How can I use `substr()` for this purpose?

Comment: `if (Substr($MyString,0,3)=="011") { echo $MyString;} `

Comment: `echo substr($number,0,3) == '011' ? $number : '';` **assuming your values are really strings**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Mark, you can use `substr` as follows:

```
$string = substr($longstring,0,3);
if($string == '011'){
   echo $longstring;
}
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Not a regex solution though.